# Can I pass Parallel Route slots to Template instead of Layout? (NEXT.JS)

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I'm working on my first Next.js project, and would like to know if it is possible to use the optional template.js instead  of the mandatory root layout to define the slots for Parallel routes?

My  parallel routes are defined on the root level of the App, and I have gotten it to work when passing the slots to the root layout, but was wondering if this is possible, because it might help me fix some other stuff that is unrelated to this question.

the  folder structure is kind of like this right now:

```
app/
>@parallel1/
   >page.js
>@parallel2/
   >page.js
layout.js
template.js
page.js
```

In the docs, they only talk about placing slots to the root layout like this:

```
    export default function Layout(props) {
      return (
        <>
          {props.children}
          {props.team}
          {props.analytics}
        </>
      )
    }
```

And this I have basically gotten to work, but can I somehow do this in the template instead?

I tried to just move everything to the template, but then my slots do not render anything anymore, so before I try solving this by trial and error I started to  wonder if this is even possible in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Few points to know first:

1. A root Layout is a must to render the children in the html `<body>` tag.
2. Template sits between a Layout and Page, so it's like this:
   [image: Chart describing the structure of Layout, Template and Page in NextJs]
   2.1. All the passed elements from Layout are passed as Children to Template
3. Templates do not preserve state as Layout does, during Navigation. More info:

   - [Active state and navigation in Next.Js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes#active-state-and-navigation)
   - [Templates in Next.Js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#templates)
4. Parallel Routes only works with Layout because it maintains the states.

To answer your question, you need to have a Root Layout to render the children and due to its nature of preserving the state, any parallel slots passed to it are handled side by side and maintains the overall page layout.

In case of Template, it does not preserve the state. Therefore, if you try to use parallel routes. It's not going to maintaining the overall page layout, resulting in the render of only one slot or any children passed to it, depending on the navigation path.